# emplace_back для шаблонного конструктора

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть класс (не шаблонный и шаблонным его делать нельзя) с шаблонным конструктором:

```
class Foo  
{  
public:  
    Foo() = delete;  
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete; 

    template<typename T>  
    Foo(const T& _val)  
    {  
        std::cout << _val << std::endl;  
    }  
};
```

В дальнейшем этот класс будет храниться в std::vector.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Foo> vect;
    vect.emplace_back(3);

    return 0;
}
```

Но при попытке вызова emplace_back компилятор (gcc 4.8.1) выдает ошибку:

> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:64:0,
>
> ```
>              from main.cpp:3:
> ```
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_construct.h:  In instantiation of 'void
>   std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = Foo; _Args = {Foo}]':
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:75:53:   required from
>   'static _ForwardIterator
>   std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator; _ForwardIterator = Foo*; bool
>   _TrivialValueTypes = false]'
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:117:41:   required from
>   '_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator,
>   _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator; _ForwardIterator = Foo*]'
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:258:63:   required from
>   '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator,
>   _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator; _ForwardIterator = Foo*; _Tp = Foo]'
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:281:69:   required from
>   '_ForwardIterator
>   std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a(_InputIterator,
>   _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Allocator&) [with _InputIterator = Foo*; _ForwardIterator = Foo*; _Allocator = std::allocator]'
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/vector.tcc:415:43:   required from 'void
>   std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_emplace_back_aux(_Args&& ...) [with _Args
>   = {int}; _Tp = Foo; _Alloc = std::allocator]'
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/vector.tcc:101:54:   required from 'void
>   std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args =
>   {int}; _Tp = Foo; _Alloc = std::allocator]'
>
> main.cpp:99:24:   required from here
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted
>   function 'Foo::Foo(const Foo&)'
>
> ```
>  { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
> ```
>
> main.cpp:88:5: error: declared here
>
> ```
>  Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
> ```

Есть способ заставить emplace_back работать в данном случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно. Следует только определить конструктор копирования или перемещения. Этот конструктор требуется, так как уже существующие элементы могут переноситься в новый буфер при росте контейнера.

Comment: А поясните следующий момент: если я правильно понимаю, то наличие конструктора копирования или перемещения важно для вектора (чтобы можно было увеличивать размер контейнера), но ошибка возникает только если в коде есть вызов emplace_back. Почему не ругается на отсутствие конструктора копирования при создании вектора, а ругается при попытке добавить в него элемента?

Comment: @mnipilin Потому что в конструкторе вектора по умолчанию не вызывается функция "расширить вектор", а при `emplace_back` это вполне возможно

Comment: @mnipilin: Наличие конструктора копирования или перемещения важно не для вектора в целом, а для некоторых конкретных отдельных методов вектора. Каждый метод шаблонного класса является самостоятельным шаблоном, который инстанциируется индивидуально и независимо от самого шаблона класса. Шаблоны методов вашего вектора инстанциируются в том и только в том случае, если они используются в программе. В данном случае, до тех пор прока вы не инстанцируете какой-то метод вектора, который пытается использовать конструкторы копирования/перемещения, наличия таких конструкторов требоваться не будет.

Comment: У вас эти конструкторы нужны только в `emplace_back`. Поэтому как только вы "тронули" `emplace_back`, сразу же полезли ошибки компиляции.